# Exhaust Fan in small half bathroom on first floor

Tags: bathroom, fans, exhaust

[image]

Hi, I would like to add an exhaust fan in my small half bathroom on the first floor (it’s a 2 floor semi-attached home).  The bathroom becomes very humid and takes a few minutes to eliminate odors.  I’m planning to hire an electrician to install the fan with a switch button.  Based on the picture, can you please advise if I can add a fan directly to this exhaust/air duct vent or if I’m required to have an insulation tube leading outside the roof.  The house is a flat roof and I don’t have an access point to the attic (or area between my celing and roof).  Also, my electrician has sent a few fan suggestions but they are not appealing as they look like attic or laundromat fans.  Does anyone have an exhaust fan suggestion that can fit into this vent and appealing (preferably white colored)?  The measurements of the vent are 14 inches by height and 13 inches by width.  Thank you so much for your support.

Here are some photos of the vent behind the grill:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I should have also noted that I have just purchased this home and I am a first time home buyer, so I’m not sure sure how this vent was previously built or set up.

Comment: Does this house have central HVAC? What is that lower opening in the wall?

Comment: Where is this property located?

Comment: This house doesn’t have central HVAC.  The bottom opening is a window with privacy glass leading to the kitchen (not sure why it was installed there as it seems useless).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove that grill and find out what's behind . Hopefully, there will be some sort of duct work that vents to the outside. You do not want to vent humid air into plain wall space. There are many fans to choose from so look around. I would tend to look more on efficiency than appealing. You can always spray paint it white.

Here is a typical bathroom exhaust fan that has a 13.5" by 13.5" grill and 14.25" x 14.25" housing. It vents to the back.
[image]

here is a link to the site so you can get more info.

https://www.zoro.com/broan-fan-wall-10-38-in-506mg/i/G3064914/#specifications

you should also try to clean out as much of the debris from the duck as possible. It will help with the air flow.

Comment: Thank you Jack for getting back to me.  I’ll check out what’s behind the vent.  Do you have any example of what type of fans can be installed here?  My electrician had recommended a shutter fan but it just doesn’t seem to fit in a bathroom to me. Thanks again.

Comment: I have finally had a chance to remove the cover and it appears to be a vent behind it that goes upward (assuming the roof).  Can you please review the photos I have attached and advise if I can install the suggested fan directly into it or do I need to attach a hose leading through the vent?  Also, can you please share the link the fan you have previously suggested as I’m unable to find it online.  Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a better fan that vents straight back. Also included a link for the fan.

Comment: Thanks Jack for sharing the link and new fan.  I would prefer one that is operated via a switch rather than a pull. It will be great if you can help me find one.   For my own awareness, can you please clarify if I have sufficient duct work for a fan, or do I still need to add a flexible foil duct/hose that are typically connected to an exhaust fan?

Comment: Your electrician will have no problem bypassing the pull chain for a switch. This fan is for 10.375" diameter  duct, your sheet metal duct is approximately 14"x14" so it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I’ll share this one with my electrician.  Can I ask you why the original fan you had shared will not work for this duct? I liked the look of it and also curious on why it’s not suitable.

Comment: That first fan vented to the side so when it was installed, it's vent would be right up against the side of your duct, restricting the air flow. The latest fan vents straight back so it's air flow will be straight down your duct work.